# remove packaged from installed ubuntu from livecd

Tags: live-cd

I cant boot into my ubuntu system due to a boot problem I am trying to fix. One of the suggestions I have had to fix it is to purge any nvidia restricted drivers installed. How can I gain access to the terminal for the installed ubuntu from the terminal from livecd for me to remove the nvidia packaged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot the Ubuntu Live CD, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

If you created a custom partition layout when installing Ubuntu you have to find your root partition using the `fdisk` utility. See the section Finding your root partition.

```
$ sudo chroot /mnt
```